# Proper way to call javascript handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a huge JS file and want to divide it, for example, I have this one:

**page.html**

```
<!-- some tags and jquery include... -->
<script src="example.js"></script>
<!-- externalHandlers only needs for second example, in original working example It's empty -->
<script src="externalHandlers.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var something = new Something('someValue');
    );
</script>
<!-- some tags... -->
```

**example.js**

```
var Something = (function (document) {
    "use strict";
    var Something = function(x){
        //initialize some stuff
    };
    Something.prototype.func1 = function(){
        //do things
    }

    Something.prototype.func2 = function(){
        //do things
    }

    //more funcs
    $(document).on('click', 'a.some-class', function (e) {
        //do things when click
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'a.some-class-2', function (e) {
        //do things when click
    });

    return Something;

})(document);
```

Above code works fine, but I want to externalize click handlers in another js file. I tried this:

**example.js** (new)

```
var Something = (function (document) {
    "use strict";
    var Something = function(x){
        //initialize some stuff
    };
    Something.prototype.func1 = function(){
        //do things
    }

    Something.prototype.func2 = function(){
        //do things
    }

    //more funcs
    $(document).on('click', 'a.some-class', handlerFunction);

    $(document).on('click', 'a.some-class-2', function (e) {
        //do things when click
    });

    return Something;    

})(document);
```

**externalHandlers.js**

```
function handlerFunction(){
    //do some stuff
}
```

But browser console show me errors

> ReferenceError: handlerFunction is not defined
>
> TypeError: Something is not a constructor

How can I do something like that I want? It's possible?

Comment: You should be encountering another error, `handlerFunction is not defined`, which is the source of the (second) `Something` error, is that what you're seeing?

Comment: That's true, I didn't see it, first error is `handlerFunction is not defined`

Comment: `prototype` inside `IIFE` ? Is is necessary ??

Comment: @brk It's a common enough pattern for encapsulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `externalHandlers` runs first, so that `handlerFunction` is defined when `example.js` runs, so that `example.js` can properly reference `handlerFunction` without an error, and so that `Something` gets defined properly:

```
<script src="externalHandlers.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same function name in both files? Make sure the scripts are actually running in the desired order (which they should be if they're set out like in the answer)

Comment: Finally works, instead use a normal function for handler I use another ``IIFE`` and initialize it inside ``Something`` initializer. I tried this before but with your answer now works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalHandlers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var something = new Something('someValue');
     });
</script>
```

Comment: The placement of the `$(document).ready(` shouldn't have any impact on the problem OP is facing.